# How was law enforcement handled in medieval China before professional police?

Tags: middle-ages, medieval-china, early-medieval, police

This question came from:

[How was law enforcement handled in large US cities before professional police?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/how-was-law-enforcement-handled-in-large-us-cities-before-professional-police)

China (Zhōng Gúo 中国) has had very large cities with more than a million people since the early middle ages. For example [Chang'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27an) (长安) around the years 600 to 900 had approximately 2 million people. How did they manage law enforcement and control before modern times?

Comment: There's a history section on [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_enforcement_in_China) on law enforcement in China.

Comment: I know I asked the other one, but I really like this question.

Comment: The Wikipedia article linked above has literally no information on Medieval China (Tang for Chang An as in the question, or Yuan and Ming for the later; only Song is mentioned very briefly).

Comment: @Ludi - I think I've clarified the English. Hopefully the poster doesn't feel I changed the meaning beyond repair.